# Этимология слова "черенок" в значении кошелёк, использованное Гоголем?

Tags: этимология

В произведении "Тарас Бульба" Н.В.Гоголя присутствует следующая фраза: "... снявши с него саблю с дорогою рукоятью и отвязавши от пояса целый **черенок** с червонцами".

Очевидно (и подтверждается сносками в различных изданиях), что под словом черенок имеется ввиду кошелёк. Однако ни в каком из известных словарей, в т.ч. украинских данное значение не встречается. Откуда же происходит употребление слова в данном значении?

Answer (score 5):

[Согласно Далю](http://www.infoliolib.info/sprav/dal/01/1889.html) `черес` (он же чересел, чресленик, чресельник) это "долгий кошель кишкой, в котором носят деньги, опоясываясь под одеждой". [Слово](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81_(%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81)) это действительно имеет малороссийский колор и происходит от "чересла" ("поясница") - те самые чересла, которые до сих иногда можно услышать в выражении "чересла болят".

Ну а `черенок` - это просто уменьшительное.

Ну и ещё добавлю, что слово это никогда не было общепонятным, вот, читателям пушкинского "Современника" тоже [приходится](https://books.google.de/books?id=rCYYAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA54&dq=%22%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8A%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZ_ounvrjdAhVR-aQKHWtTBoUQ6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=%22%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8A%22&f=false) разъяснять:

> Несмотря на то, что малѣйшее движеніе причиняло ему нестерпимыя страданія, онъ просилъ снять съ лѣвой ноги чересокъ (*) съ деньгами. Ужасно тяжелое чувство произвелъ во мнѣ видь его голой, бѣлой и здоровой ноги, когда съ нея сняли сапогъ и развязывали **чересъ**.
>
> — Тутъ три монеты и полтинникъ, сказалъ онъ мнѣ въ то время, какъ я бралъ въ руки **чересъ**: — ужъ вы ихъ сберегите.
>
> ---
>
> (*) **Чересъ** — кошелекъ въ видѣ пояска, который солдаты носятъ обыкновенно подъ колѣномъ.

Comment: уменьшительная форма *черес* должна была бы быть *черешок*, но при этом она совпадает с синонимом слова *черенок* - так же **черешок**, видимо поэтому произошёл перенос значения

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка ну вот такой вот был Гоголь неграмотный, не знал как правильно.  В целом хочу заметить, что в разговорной речи часто бывает всякое (что не отменяет каких-то объективных присущих языку черт)

Comment: позвольте попросить вас не приписывать мне того, чего я не говорил, и о чём даже не подумал, не нужно домысливать за собеседника, что касается Гоголя, то он пользовался тем языком, который он слышал, авторство черенка в значении кошелька ему не принадлежит, автор - народ, грамотность здесь не при чём

Comment: Я вам ничего не приписывал.

Comment: "ну вот такой вот был Гоголь неграмотный, не знал как правильно" - то есть, обращаясь ко мне, эту фразу вы написали всерьёз, а не с сарказмом, и действительно так считаете?

Comment: Извините, я был в пути и не имел возможности ответить. Примите, пожалуйста, мои заверения - я не хотел вас обидеть.